# Problem updating a sql view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I am having a problem with a sql view.  My actual views encompass several joins, but for the purposes of my question I will demonstrate the issue with smaller examples.

Say I have the views…

```
create view A
as
    select Id as IdC
    from tableA
go

create view B
as
    select b.Id, 
            b.Name, 
            a.*
    from tableB b 
    inner join A a on a.Id = b.Id
go
```

So all is well.  Then I change view A to read…

```
alter view A
as
    select Id as IdColumn
    from tableA
go
```

So now if I write…

```
select * from A
```

It returns column `IdColumn`

However, if I write…

```
select * from B
```

It returns the original `IdC` column name from view A

I tried `sp_refreshview`, but that has not helped.

How can I get view B to return the updated column name from view A?

UPDATE **

Well I messed up the original question.  I thank everyone for their responses.  I intend to join view A to table B in view B.  It seems the alter statement on view B solves the issue.

Comment: Your view `B` doesn't reference view `A`...

Comment: Uh, I'm confused - View "B" seems to be selecting directly from the Table - "TableA" - so why would you expect it to return a column alias defined in View "A" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the problem with `select *`

If you would have referenced View A

```
create view B 
as
     select b.Id,
              b.Name,
              a.*
     from tableB b
     inner join A  on a.Id = b.Id
```

Altering View A returned columns (add, delete, rename) will not be reflected in view B until you **Alter** view B. Same thing happens in UDF's and Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 4):

As I can see you query you are refering tableA not view A

```
select b.Id, 
            b.Name, 
            a.*
    from tableB b 
    inner join tableA a on a.Id = b.Id
```

So modify the above query will resolve you issue

**Modified query for view B**

```
 select b.Id, 
                b.Name, 
                a.*
        from tableB b 
        inner join A a on a.IdColumn = b.Id
```

Answer (score 3):

Your viewB is joining tableA, not view A, try:

```
inner join A a on a.Id = b.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

View B doesn't have anything to to with View A.

In View B you have TableA and TableB

Try instead:

```
alter view B
as
    select b.Id, 
            b.Name, 
            a.*
    from tableB b 
    inner join A a on a.IdColumn = b.Id
go
```